# PHP/MYSQL - Syntax error relating to a mysql query through as php variable

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

I am having a problem with syntax errors in the following variable:

```
$uploadQuery = "
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$docRoot."/../../includes/dbUploads/".$fileToUpload."' 
INTO TABLE `promotions` 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
ESCAPED BY '\\' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'  
";
```

I know that it has something do do with the escaping of the `'` characters in the LOAD DATA... line. But I am stumped when it comes to what exactly the problem is, or how to reword this query in the correct manner.

So, My question is this:

How do i reword the stated variable in the correct manner, as to have no syntax errors relating to it.

If anyone has any suggestions or input with this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You!

Comment: What is your error exactly? Also, did you try to echo $uploadQuery instead of running it from php, and then run it manually and see how can be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Missing an escape character, this is the correct string:

```
$uploadQuery = "
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$docRoot."/../../includes/dbUploads/".$fileToUpload."' 
INTO TABLE `promotions` 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
ESCAPED BY '\\' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\\r\\n'  
";
```

Note the extra `\` on the 5th line. It was treating the `"` as a string terminator. Also another problem (that doesn't cause a syntax error) is on the 7th line, you need to escape the backslashes.

P.S. the markup analyzer even picked it up :P

Edit: you probably also need to change line 7 to `ESCAPED BY '\\\\'` since this reduces to `ESCAPED BY '\\'` after PHP parses it.

Comment: Thanks alot! I guess i did not "know" after all... The root of my problem that :)

Comment: By the way, you don't have to concatenate variables to a string if you are using double quotes `"`. For instance, if you say `echo "$foo"` it will work just like if you said `echo $foo`. Just note that in some cases you will need to wrap the variable in `{` and `}` so that it can be differentiated from the rest of the string's text.

Comment: @imkingdavid if i do not concatenate them, it produces more syntax errors for some reason? But generally i do not.

Comment: You have to insert the variable into the string like: `"ABC $var"`.

Comment: @BlackberryFan what errors? You should be able to just put, for instance, `LOAD DATA INFILE '{$docRoot}/../../includes/dbUploads/{$fileToUpload}' INTO TABLE` etc. as long as the string itself is wrapped in `"` so you don't have to escape the `'`

Comment: @imkingdavid That makes a lot more sense, thank you so much :) useful!